# Trying to get property of non-object, and IS an object

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
$value = app\models\SectionTranslation::find()
 ->select(['section_id', 'name'])
 ->where(['=', 'section_id', $iSection['id']])
 ->andWhere(['=', 'language_id', $lang])
 ->one();
$nam = $value->name;
```

I want to use $value->name but I can't. I get "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" error. But if I write

```
var_dump($nam);exit;
```

after the last line of code, I can show correctly the result on my screen:

```
string(10) "Tree"
```

Any idea of the problem or the solution?

Thanks you.

Comment: Please share all code where it fails. Maybe you overwrite the $value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Seems like you're looking at the wrong line.

Comment: I would simplify the code, because you are trying to get the model object, so

`$value = app\models\SectionTranslation::find()
->where(['section_id' => $iSection['id'],  'language_id' => $lang])
->one();`

test if value is not false and then try to use $value->name (or whatever property that object is supposed to have)

Comment: @AramGrigoryan is all code shared. var_dump line is just below the first piece of code.

Comment: @Nimer I just test it but same problem..

Comment: Ok is solucionated, the problem was that this part of code was into foreach, and first iteration was ok, but in 4th crashed. Thanks you.